# Should a question about a bug in software be answered or closed when the bug is fixed?

Tags: discussion, policy, self-answer

To give you a specific example, I have asked [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1827917/570020), but then realized it must be a bug in the software and created [this bug report](https://github.com/gwsw/less/issues/474). The bug was quickly fixed, but the question itself remains unanswered.

My first intuition was to delete the question, because it is no longer relevant. But keeping it may be beneficial for other people wondering, like me, if the buggy behaviour was there for a reason and they missed something in the documentation.

I checked that the bug was introduced in the release from Dec 30, 2020 and the fix is yet to be released, which gives quite a few misbehaving versions out there. Thus right now I lean more towards answering the question.

What would you recommend, answer my own question, or delete it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Yes, the question should be answered

A bug being fixed is an *excellent* candidate for an answer to a question. It neatly encapsulates that: there was a problem, the developers confirmed it, they fixed it and now the problem does not exist. That's the ideal closing of the loop.

Answering the question is good for you, and good for the community.

Comment: Absolutely. For future users it also can give a "if you have version x which has the bug then you need to upgrade to version y".

Comment: Thank you! I have now answered the original question, including the range of versions for which the bug occurred.